# For Malta, are there websites, to help find a partner to rent an apartment with

Tags: accommodation, malta

I am an expat living in Malta.

I would like to rent an apartment. Apartments in Malta are expensive. I would like to find someone to share an apartment with. Someone like me, who is fairly new in Malta.

I am looking for a website for people like myself who would like to match-up (team-up, pair-up) to collectively rent an apartment.

I do not want to use Facebook.

Here is want I have found.

1. [Maltapark](https://www.maltapark.com/listings/category/247)
2. [Flatmate Malta](https://lets.flatmate.com.mt/)
3. [Expat.com Malta](https://www.expat.com/en/housing/europe/malta/)

My current problem is those sites have no offers for the towns I am interested in ( Qormi,   Santa Lucia,   Gudja, Ghaxaq,   Zetjun,   Tarxien,   Paola,   Fgura,   Zebbug,   Siggiewi,   Mqabba,   Kirkop,   Safi,   Zurrieq,   Qrendi)

Can somebody recommend a website that could help me?

(I posted a related question about accomodation classifieds in Maltese newspapers:
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159684/which-maltese-print-or-online-newspaper-has-a-section-with-offers-for-renting-a)